# Change cell focus on keypress

Tags: javascript, html, dom-events, keyboard-events

I'm trying to achieve something I'm not sure will ever work. What I wish to do is to change cell focus when the user presses any letter key. I also wish the letter to appear in the source cell but not in the destination cell. What I tried to do is:

**User marks a cell by clicking on it**

```
table.onclick = function tableMouseListener(event) {
  markedCell = event.target;
  markedCellRow = markedCell.parentNode.rowIndex;
  markedCellCol = markedCell.cellIndex;
};
```

**User writes an A in marked cell**

```
$(document).keypress(function(e){
  if (e.keyCode == 65) {
    markedCell.appendChild(document.createTextNode(String.fromCharCode(e.keyCode)));
    jumpToNextCell();
  }    
});
```

**After the A has been typed, jump to the next cell and focus it**

```
function jumpToNextCell() {
  table = document.getElementById('myTable');
  markedCellCol++;
  markedCell = table.rows[markedCellRow].cells[markedCellCol];
  markedCell.appendChild(document.createTextNode('\u0020'));
  markedCell.focus();
}
```

The problem with the logic above is that both the source and destination cell now has the letter A in it.

Is there any way to prevent the letter from being added to the destination cell?

**EDIT**

The source cell is the one I mark and the destination cell is the one I'm jumping to.

Comment: Can you clarify what are the **source**, and **destination** cells?

Comment: What's your ("*[MCVE]*") HTML and JavaScript? Otherwise you'll get lots of guesses and probably zero useful, understandable or directly-relevant answers. Also, *without your relevant code* this question is off-topic as it both *does not contain your code*, it's not entirely clear what you're asking and it's also too broad - since you're effectively expecting us to both reproduce your existing efforts and implement a solution to your problem.

Comment: @RichardSilvertass Check my answer and accept it if it helps you.

Answer (score 0):

Clear the focused Cell after keyPress

```
markedCell.innterText='';
```

in JQuery syntax

```
$('#markedCellSelector').val('');
```

Answer (score 0):

I created a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/LeoAref/ve88kevs/) that implements the whole feature

And here is the `JS` code:

```
var btns = Array.prototype.slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('button')),
    markedBtn;

btns.forEach(function(btn) {
    btn.addEventListener('click', function(){
        btns.forEach(function(btn) {
            btn.classList = Array.prototype.slice.call(btn.classList).filter(function(className) {
                return className !== 'marked';
            });
        });

        btn.className += ' marked';
        markedBtn = this;
    });
});

document.addEventListener('keyup', function(e) {
    var char = String.fromCharCode(e.which);

    if(markedBtn) {
        markedBtn.innerText = char;

        if(markedBtn.nextElementSibling) {
            markedBtn = markedBtn.nextElementSibling;
            markedBtn.click();
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Can this be implemented for a table with editable cells? Because that's what I'm using.

Comment: Yes, just tell me your `HTML`, and I'll help you with implementing it

Comment: See this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/silvertassen/Lzsnf8mw/). Mark a cell and type 'r' to move right and 'd' to move down.